# Uniform convergence garantee on sample complexity

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, convergence

I can't understand why the Uniform Convergence guarantees an **upper bound** and not a **lower bound** on sample complexity as stated on [1]

> **Corollary 4.4.**
> If a class $H$ has the uniform convergence property with a function $m^{UC}_H$
> then the class is agnostically PAC learnable with the sample complexity
> $$m_H(\epsilon ,\delta) \leq m^{UC}_H(\epsilon/2,\delta)$$
> Furthermore, in that case, the $ERM_H$ paradigm is a successful agnostic
> PAC learner for $H$.

From what I understood, if we have the sample set $S$ with
$$|S| \geq m^{UC}_H(\epsilon/2,\delta) $$
then, by definition of the UC property, for every $\epsilon,\delta \in (0, 1)$ and for every probability distribution D over Z, with probability of at least $1 − \delta$, $S$ is $\epsilon/2$-representative.

Then, by Lemma 4.3,
$$L_D(h_S) \leq min_{h \in H}{L_D(h) +\epsilon},\ h_S = ERM_H(S)$$
Therefore, by definition, the class $H$ is agnostic PAC learnable
with a sample complexity
$$m_H(\epsilon, \delta) \geq m^{UC}_H(\epsilon/2,\delta)$$

Is that proof correct? Thank you.

[1] Understanding Machine Learning By Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David, pag 32 ([https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/))